# Skip iteration when a column is all NAs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I have bunch of dataset to process a calculation. However, sometime the variable I need to work on is empty -- all `NA`s. When this condition meets, I need to skip that iteration/dataset and move to the next iteration. A sample dataset would be:

```
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
# this is the dataset for this iteration--
data <- data.frame(id = c(10,20,30,40,50),
                   score.1 = c(15,16,17,18,19),
                   var1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

> data
  id score.1 var1
1 10      15   NA
2 20      16   NA
3 30      17   NA
4 40      18   NA
5 50      19   NA

for (v in 1:length(vector)) {
  

  data2$var2 <- data$var1 + vector[v]
  
}
```

I tried this if condition but I think I could not achieve.

```
for (v in 1:length(vector)) {
  
  if(data$var1 == NA) next
  data$var2 <- data$var1 + vector[v]
  
}
```

I also would like to know which dataset has this `var1` variable missing. Is it possible to include such warning after all iterations finish?

Comment: `if (all(is.na(data$var1))) next`

Comment: one more thing. How can I produce a warning message? so that I know which dataset has the missing `var1` variable?

Comment: You could do `if (all(is.na(data$var1))) { warning("Dataset xx has only missings in column var1."); next }` to add a warning. BTW: Instead of checking inside the loop you could check outside of the loop and run the loop only if any non-NAs.

Comment: if you can post this, I will mark it. thanks for your time again.